# Is there a way to calculate gas usage of external function call?

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate

I have an external view function which has an iteration loop. If the contract's `totalSupply` gets bigger, then the iteration time will grow as well. I'm testing on rinkeby right now, but when I launch it on mainnet, and if lots of users gets involved, I'm concerned about the function call hits the block gas limit. So I want to calculate the maximum iteration time of the function, but I have no idea how to do it. Here's my function.

```
function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) external view returns(uint256[] ownerTokens) {
    uint256 tokenCount = balanceOf(_owner);

    if (tokenCount == 0) {
        // Return an empty array
        return new uint256[](0);
    } else {
        uint256[] memory result = new uint256[](tokenCount);
        uint256 totalItems = totalSupply();
        uint256 resultIndex = 0;

        uint256 itemId;

        for (itemId = 1; itemId <= totalItems; itemId++) {
            if (itemIndexToOwner[itemId] == _owner) {
                result[resultIndex] = itemId;
                resultIndex++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `view` function doesn't cost any gas, because it is not executed by miner.

Comment: @goodvibration Even if there's some writings on memory array when iterating the loop? I'm confused little bit.

Comment: As long as it's not a state variable - no.